# Force media info rewrite with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, codec, h.265

I have a bunch of video files created by MKVToolnix that have a Codec ID like: V_MS/VFW/FOURCC / HEVC.

I tried to run this:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -c copy test.avi
```

to turn it to avi and then this:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i test.avi -c:v copy -c:a copy  test2.mkv
```

to convert it back to mkv

Now the file has the correct Codec ID: V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC

I need this because while test.mkv will not play on Kodi, test2.mkv will do.

Hence the question: can I do it in just one passage, i.e. **force the fixing of the codec ID** keeping all the streams and metadata of the original file?

Thanks to everyone,

Fabio

Comment: You may chain the two commands using a pipe: `ffmpeg -i test.mkv -c copy -f avi pipe: | ffmpeg -y -fflags +genpts -f avi -vcodec hevc -i pipe: -c:v copy -c:a copy test2.mkv`. In case you want me to try a simpler solution, please share a sample input video file (share using Google Drive for example).

Comment: Share the full log of `ffmpeg -i test.mkv -i test2.mkv`

Comment: Thank you for the answers. In the meantime I have found a workaround using mkvmerge instead of ffmpeg. Apparently the command 

mkvmerge --output test2.mkv test.mkv

does the job.

Thanks for your answers,

Fabio